# Cannot find icon for Mono Develop for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04, monodevelop

I'm new to ubuntu 9.04 os and I have installed mono develop 2.4 from terminal successfully.

But surprisingly I could not find any icon on my desktop to launch Mono Develop. How can I solve the above issue and how can I create a icon on desktop to launch Mono Develop

Answer (score 4):

you can either start it via command line and type `monodevelop`, or hit `alt-f2` and enter monodevelop or click your application menu (upper right corner, `alt-f1`) go to programming and start monodevelop

Comment: ... or click the application menu, navigate to MonoDevelop, right-click on its menu entry, and put an icon for it on the panel.

Comment: @CarlF: or put the icon on the desktop ;)